# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use the rotate-screen module in tkinter on Raspberry Pi 4: What can I do to resolve 'No module named win32api'?

Tags: tkinter, winapi, raspberry-pi4

Hi I am trying to make a GUI with tkinter. I want this for my raspberry pi 4 in combination with a screen. I want the screen to be vertical and found only one way to do this, via: import rotate screen. I installed this, but when I ran my code I got the error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'. I've looked up how to install win32api, but nothing worked for me. Does anyone have any advice?

I've tried:

pip install pywin32
pip install pywin32==300
pip install pipywin32

And more like this.

I was hoping this would just install the package, but unfortunately not.
I always got error messages.

Comment: win32api is strictly for windows machines. It's not going to work on a non-windows machine.

Comment: This will update version 306   python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install